# Unable to click on element when browser does not show up in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium web driver 2.37.0 and java.
Here is a simple java program that clicks on an element.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/mac-mini");
    WebElement checkAvailabilityLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'retail-availability-search-trigger-block cold-start']//button"));
    checkAvailabilityLink.click();
    WebElement zipCode = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id = 'retail-availability-search-query']"));
    zipCode.sendKeys("33180");
    WebElement searchStores = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='retail-availability-search-search-button']"));
    searchStores.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
    WebElement selectStore = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='retail-availability-search-select-store-button']"));
    selectStore.click();
```

When the browser shows up the this code works fine.
When the opened browser is minimized/some other window is opened it doesnot show up the stores even if the SearchStoreButton is clicked.
Dont understand why is this issue.

Comment: Well what error do you get?

Comment: @Arran It says selectStore element can not be found because when SearchStore button is clicked it displays the resultant stores and then SelectStore button gets visible.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you minimize the window or open another tab([switching into another window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)), the webdriver cannot access the DOM in requested window.

You can also see [how selenium "Emulate the User"](http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html) at **#16.3.2. Emulate the User**.

```
# native-events approach 
Sadly, this approach is only possible where WebDriver can bind closely with 
the browser and where the development team have determined how best to send 
native events without requiring the browser window to be focused (as Selenium 
tests take a long time to run, and it's useful to be able to use the machine 
for other tasks as they run). At the time of writing, this means that native 
events can be used on Linux and Windows, but not Mac OS X.
```

It's recommended that when you do browser automation with webdriver, you should not interrupt the automated process, just let it run as the steps you've set.

You can use [RemoteWebDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver), if you want continue the work in the same machine where you run the selenium codes.

Here are some resources that may help you to setup selenium-server

- [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)
  Use this program when you want to run selenium tests in Linux server.
- [Official Selenium Docker image](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

  Setup [selenium-grid](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) to provide a convenient, stable and flexible environment run tests.